# Oracle Turkish Character could not be displayed

Tags: c#, oracle

i have a .net application (Winforms application) that connect to oracle database via System.Data.OracleClient.
when i querying the database, i see "?" instead of turkish characters. but there is a delphi application that use same database (and same database user) it can be displayed turkish characters such as "İ, Ş, Ğ, Ü" etc.

i have a same problem with toad and pl/sql Developer. i think delphi application can display turkish character to set extra parameter in connection string.(i set "encoding=true" but it is not working)

i run this query to show nls_lang values;

```
select DECODE(parameter, 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'CHARACTER SET',
'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'LANGUAGE',
'NLS_TERRITORY', 'TERRITORY') name,
value from v$nls_parameters
WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY')
```

this shows me those values;

```
1   LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
2   TERRITORY   AMERICA
3   CHARACTER SET   AL32UTF8
```

at last, when i update "?" to turkish character (such as "Ş") on pl/sql developer, my .net application shows correctly. but i can't replace all "?" values to turkish character.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already solved the issue. I am wondering if you get any hint on a missing NLS_LANG environment variable setting especially when firing up PL/SQL Developer. NLS_LANG simply tells the OCI interface which character-set is expected. The translation happens when data ist transferred between DB-Server and client.

Independent from that. If you are not sure use select DUMP(*stingcol*) from *table* and the statement will return the real values stored as well as the character set.

PL/SQL Developer or SQL/Detective use the DOA Components (Allround Automation). But Delphi applications can make use of different DB components that provide different ways to specify and handle character conversion after the query result arrives.

In your specific case as neither the .net application nor the two tools showed the characters correctly ('?'). The parameters you queried are the NLS parameters for the DB side.

So you have at least 2 options

1. The controls are not UNICODE aware
2. NLS_LANG not set - the client is assuming US7ASCII or WE8ISO8859P1

If your tools are not dead old, all of them are UNICODE aware. Today in general you the FireDAC Explorer provides you a report that shows the relevant settings the connection uses. For example

...[image: FireDAC Connection Info]

When NLS_LANG is missing or 'wrong' your application can successfully read and write it's own data but no one else can.